# Task progress as factor of user completed steps

Tags: usability, website-design, interaction-design, user-behavior, data

**The use case here is quite simple:**

1. The user has a list of tasks (first image)
2. Each task has a set of steps (second image - opened in a "drawer" of sorts)
3. In order for a task to be completed, the user has to mark all of its steps as complete.
4. The logical progression of the steps - "step 1" has to be completed before "step 2", and so on.
5. Clicking "Complete" on a Step "enables" the next step, and allows the user to Complete it. Once every step is complete, the task status is set to complete as well.

**The doubts/issues I'm having with the current design revolve around:**

1. If user hits "Complete" on a step by mistake, there should be a way for them to edit it after the fact.
2. If the previous is true, what happens when a user has Step 1 through 4 completed, but needs to revert Step 2 to "Incomplete"(an edge case, yes, but it was brought up in a demo and I need to address it)? The only logical thing to do in this case would be to disable Steps 3 and 4 until the user completes Step 2.

**What I'm looking for is:**

1. Some critique/validation/input on the UX/Design.
2. Suggestions on how to solve issue #2 above.

Thanks!

[image: Task List]

[image: Task Steps Open]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some critique/validation/input on the UX/Design.
Suggestions on how to solve issue #2 above.

1. In order to get a validation for your design, I would suggest to test it with you actual users. From my side, the design seems understandable.
   Maybe you consider, on top of your design, having a different page for each task (If this wasn't already in your mind).
2. As for the issue #2, if the steps are co-dependent, and the user reverts Step 2 to "Incomplete", I would notify the user that the Steps 3 & 4 will be marked as incomplete too (because ...give some reasoning) or maybe ask them if they should be marked as incomplete (in case that you are not sure). You could have this as an option when you create the tasks so that you can avoid confusion. Take for example Jira: The subtasks are not co-dependent and you can finish the tasks in any sequence that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it helps! I did consider having a page dedicated to each task, but accessibility and quickly marking off steps trumped it - I wanted to make sure users didn't have to navigate back and forth between pages on the app. On issue #2, I'm definitely going with a warning message + requiring users to enter a comment prior to completing a step (similar to commit messages being required by git). Cheers and thanks again!